# SOAPHandler handleFault

Tags: java, web-services

Can any one explain me when `SOAPHandler`'s `handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context)` method is called ?

My Handler class is :

```java
public class WebServiceHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private void dumpSOAPMessage(SOAPMessage msg) {
        if (msg == null) {
            System.out.println("SOAP Message is null");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        System.out.println("DUMP OF SOAP MESSAGE");
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            msg.writeTo(baos);
            System.out.println(baos.toString(getMessageEncoding(msg)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        try {
            dumpSOAPMessage(((SOAPMessageContext) context).getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside handle fault:: " + context);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        Set<QName> set = new HashSet<QName>();
        return set;
       }
}
```

Can any one explain when `handleMessage` and `handleFault` method is called ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html#wp222524

handleMessage :

> The Handler.handleMessage() method is called to intercept a SOAP
>   message request before and after it is processed by the back-end
>   component

and

handleFault :

> Implement this method to handle processing of any SOAP faults
>   generated by the handleMessage() method, as well as faults generated
>   by the back-end component.

Comment: I believe the described invocation of `handleFault(..)` is not true for pure JAX-WS. Only vendor specific code will do this. In the given link this would be the **WebLogic Server**, see [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html#wp222477).

Answer (score 4):

implementation to show handle fault

```java
    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
        SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
        SOAPFault fault = body.getFault();
        String code = fault.getFaultCode();
        String faultString = fault.getFaultString();
        Detail detail = fault.getDetail();
        
        if(detail!=null){
          Iterator<SOAPElement> iter = detail.getChildElements();
          //Getting first level of detail       
          HashMap<String, String> detailMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
          while(iter.hasNext()){
            SOAPElement element = iter.next();
            detailMap.put(element.getLocalName(), element.getValue());
          }
         //Logging or whatever
        }
        
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: at deatailmap I can get de error data, but inner in callHandlersOnResponse() the exception is always without data